# Lua matching wrong pattern

Tags: text, lua, lua-patterns

I need to match string and return (\aHEX) and (text).

And use it like

```lua
for k, v in string.gmatch("Default \aFFFFFFFFWhite text \aFF0000FFJust red text", "<pattern>") do
    -- k = "" / "\aFFFFFFFF" / "\aFF0000FF"
    -- v = "Default" / "White text " / "Just red text"
end
```

tried this

```lua
local text = "Default \aFF00FFFFRed text\a00FF00FFGreen";

for k, v in text:gmatch("(\a%x%x%x%x%x%x%x%x)(%w+)") do
    print(string.format("%s: %s", k, v));
    -- \aFF00FFFF: Red
    -- \a00FF00FF: Green
end
```

Missing "Default" and " text"

Comment: Changing that `(%w+)` to `([%w%s]+)` can help you get the " text"  part. But I'm not sure how to handle the beginning of the text.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot make a sequence of patterns optional with Lua patterns. Please check if https://ideone.com/o4kTeA solves your issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nearly, " text" part is in next part without color

Comment: Do you need it like in https://ideone.com/A3uVf0 ?

Comment: Yes, @WiktorStribiżew, can u write it like the solution to the post, for accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot make a sequence of patterns optional with Lua patterns.

You can use

```lua
local text = "Default \aFF00FFFFRed text\a00FF00FFGreen";
 
for word in text:gmatch("\a?[^\a]+") do
  k, v = word:match("^(\a%x%x%x%x%x%x%x%x)(%w+)$")
  if k then
     print(string.format("%s: %s", k, v));
  else
     print(word)
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Default 
FF00FFFFRed text
00FF00FF: Green
```

*Details*:

- `\a?[^\a]+` matches all occurrences of sequences that start with an optional `\a`, and then contain one or more chars other than `\a`
- then `^(\a%x%x%x%x%x%x%x%x)(%w+)$` is applied to each found substring, and if there is a match, the key:value pair is produced, else the whole match is the required value.